# Unknown column in foreign key definition

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, create-table

I'm trying to add a new table to an already existing database but it keeps giving me an [error "Unknown column 'product_id' in foreign key definition"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX59w.png).

```
CREATE TABLE product_review (
    prod_review_ref_no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    review TEXT NOT NULL,
    comment TEXT NOT NULL,
    date TEXT NOT NULL,
    time TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(product_id)
);
```

Any help would be appreciated,
kind regards

Comment: You don't have a column in this table named `product_id` therefore you can't make a Foreign Key relationship for that non-existent column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define your product_id column **before** setting the constraint.

Comment: Yes! If one thinks about it, there's no reason SQL can't add the column implicitly when one declares a foreign key constraint. It's not an unreasonable assumption. It would, for example, avoid cases where a developer tries to make a foreign key for a column whose data type does not match the referenced primary key. But in reality, one has to define the column separately.